# Does Android batch UI operations or re-draw every single command?

Tags: android

This question came to my mind when re-binding data to views in `RecycleView`. Before selectively applying UI changes to the views, I usually reset them all to their default states.

Such as

```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

          /* Reseting to normal/default state */
          holder.title.visibility = View.VISIBLE
          holder.poster.visibility = View.VISIBLE

          /* Applying data */
          if (data.poster.url == null) {
              holder.poster.visibility = View.GONE
          }

   }
```

Here the `poster` View has potentially its `visibility` changed to `VISIBLE` and `GONE` again within a very short time interval.

1. Does Android actually invalidate and request drawing for both visibility changes? For example, if before binding, `holder.poster` view was `GONE`, then Android would draw it visible and then gone again?
2. Or does it batch them and only execute the latest state? For example, if we want the app to run at 60fps, it might batch UI operations in 16ms intervals. I can change `Visibility` hundreds of times, but it will actually draw the very last state within that 16ms batch.

Comment: I think it *might* result in invalidation of `DisplayList`, but as long as it won't get changed (compared to the previous `DisplayList`) then no draw command will be initiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd point holds true, but for a much more simple reason in your use-case.

The `onBindViewHolder` method runs on the main thread. Thus no other operation is possible on that thread until it returns.

Every change to a view property might invalidate the view. Layouting and drawing happens once, after `onBindViewHolder` has returned.

Comment: Oh, of course. For some reason, I was thinking it kicks off RenderThread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ViewHolders are recycled. That's the reason for their existence: so that expensive-to-build ViewHolders can be recycled to display different items. Yes, you need to zero out any changes to the contents of the ViewHolder that may have been made while an item was bound to it.

Rendering is also batched. Any change you make to a View property invalidates rendering or layout (as appropriate), and layout and rendering passes occur later. Property changes on views ultimately make calls to RequestLayout(), and/or RequestRender() to schedule layout and/or rendering passes at a later time. There is virtually zero cost for the second and subsequent changes.

I'm not quite sure when "a later time" is, but there's no delay involved. Right away, for all practical purposes, but batched. Something along the lines of process all queued messages, and when there are none, start a layout pass if it's been requested.

Rendering then takes place in a separate pass, after the layout pass has taken place.

Recycler view actual does a LOT of work figuring out where items were displayed, where items will be displayed and animating between the old and new location. This occurs in the layout pass, after you have notified the `RecylerView` that items in your adapter have changed. But it's done in a batch. You can toggle away on visibility to your hearts content. Only one render pass, and one layout pass takes place. (That's a sight simplification; atypically for an Android view, internally, RecyclerView, actually executes two layout passes, but that's not something you need to know or are supposed to know. It's a hack. I THINK you're being called during the first layout pass).

With respect to toggling bits and pieces in an onBindVieHolder call... rest assured that layout and rendering for the contents of the ViewHolder have been thoroughly and completely invalidated by the time you get the call. You are about to display something else, somewhere else. So go to it!

Comment: you are right. I didn't noticed it is regarding RecyclerView.